# How to enforce convexity?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation, convex-hull

I have a problem for which the solution is known to be a *convex* $f:[a,b]\times[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ over some rectangular domain ($a<b$ and $c<d$).  There are many situations (e.g. finding solutions numerically, or generating data for machine learning applications) where one would like to perform some operation on such a function *while maintaining convexity*.

**Question: What techniques exist for "minimally modifying a function to make it convex"?**

For instance, suppose I numerically approximate the solution $f$ and the approximation turns out to not be convex.  How can I find a "closest" convex function?

The most obvious thing I can think of is to take a convex hull of the graph of $f$, but this itself seems like a non-trivial problem.  Any references are appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a physicist/mathematician, and not a CS expert.  Any literature on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is of relevance, but computing convex hulls, is one of the most well-studied algorithmic problems, we can even do it fast for low dimensions, and it is often  taught in undergraduate algorithms courses, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: what do you want to do to $f(x)=-x^2$?

Comment: @mathworker21 My hope was that this would be a studied problem, and there would be a natural answer to such situations.  If I had to guess, I'd say the case $f(x)=-x^2$ should correspond to the convex function with minimum $L^2$ distance to $f$, which in this case I think is an affine linear function.

Comment: Suppose you have a discrete set function $f: 2^{0,1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ over $n$ elements. One can ask how to extend this discrete set function to obtain a continuous function $g: [0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is convex and agrees with $f$ at the corners of the hypercube. There is a canonical way to do this and the resulting function $f^-$ is called the convex closure. However, in general, this function $f^-$ would be hard to evaluate. If it was always easy then one can minimize an arbitrary set function efficiently. See https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0322

Comment: What do you know about your $f$?